# Stop keyboard event bubbling to parent

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, dom-events

We have a pill which contains `label` and a `button`. After selecting the pill, we can remove it on `Delete` or `Backspace` key. Also the same can be deleted on button click within the pill.

**Question:** When I focus on the `button` within the pill and press either `Delete` or `Backspace` then the event on the parent is been triggered(`onKeyPress` function is been called). The issue I am facing is how to stop these keyboard events (Delete & Backspace) from been called when we are on `button`.

Tried, `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`. Nothing seems to be working.

```html
<span class="pill" tabindex="0">
  <span>Pill<span>
  <button type="button" class="btn">X</button>
</span>
```

```js
function onKeyPress(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 46:
      case 8:
        e.preventDefault();
        handleClose();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
}

function handleClose() {
  console.log('Clear the pill!');
}

document.querySelector('.pill')
    .addEventListener('keydown', onKeyPress);
document.querySelector('.btn')
    .addEventListener('click', handleClose);
```

Comment: You may want to just put `tabindex="-1"` on the `button`

Comment: @BCDeWitt that will only stop keyboard navigation to that button but I can still click using mouse and then press `Delete` or `Backspace`.

Comment: I think you can fix this by adding `if (e.target === document.querySelector('.btn') return` in the parent's listener function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stopPropagation like this. The event is bubbling up from `button` to its parent the `span`. You can check for key codes and stop propagation accordingly.

```
//Check for your specific keycodes here:
function clickButton(e){
if(e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 8)
  e.stopPropagation();
}

document.querySelector('.btn')
    .addEventListener('keydown', clickButton);
```

You can remove the check but that will not trigger even the `Enter` and `Tab` key.

Answer (score 0):

Add `tabindex="-1"` to the nested `<button>` element (you will likely want this, anyway), then handle/override focus that results from clicks. If I were building this, I would prefer focus be placed on the overall pill if I clicked anywhere on/within it, so that's what I'm demonstrating in the snippet below:

```js
function onKeyPress(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 46:
    case 8:
      console.log(`${e.target.className} is in focus`);

      handleClose(e);
      break;
    default: break;
  }
}

function handleClose(e) {
  console.log('Clear the pill!');
}

// Re-places focus after processing clicks on nested elements
const pillElement = document.querySelector('.pill');
pillElement.addEventListener('click', () => { pillElement.focus(); });

pillElement
  .addEventListener('keydown', onKeyPress);
document.querySelector('.btn')
  .addEventListener('click', handleClose);
```

```css
.pill {
  border: .25em solid black;
  padding: .25em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.pill:focus,
.pill:active {
  border-color: blue;
  outline: none;
}

.pill > .btn {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.pill > .btn:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<span class="pill" tabindex="0">
  <span>Pill</span>
  <button type="button" class="btn" tabindex="-1">&#x2715;</button>
</span>
```

Comment: Reflecting focus on the pill when button is clicked is not the case which I am looking for. I understand that this can be done but my case is how to stop the propagation to button parent?