# Div inside of another Div avoid click

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Hello my friends so this is my question i have two divs, one of them is inside of the other one
like this schema below.

```
<div class="button1" onclick={buttonOnePressed}>

   <div class="button2" onclick={buttonTwoPressed}">

   </div>

</div>
```

i Want to click on the div with class "button2" and call only one function that is the "buttonTwoPressed". But when i click on the div "button2" i accidentally also call the function "buttonOnePressed", so this way two functions are called but i just wish one. What can i do to prevent that ? Thank you for reading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Event bubbles up. Use [.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to stop it from moving to parent.

```
let buttonTwoPressed = (event) =>{
event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Similar : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68070838/10140124